# PHP cases work but not default

Tags: php, get, switch-statement

I have a few cases for pages which are being loaded using Ajax. Each case loads perfectly apart from the default at the bottom. It just doesn't display anything.

```
switch($_GET['page'])  {  

    case '#filemanager' : $page = '
        <div class="innerbox">
            <p>Demo text for the file manager page</p>
        </div>'; break;

    case '#todo' : $page = '
        <div class="innerbox">
            <p>Demo text for the to-do page</p>
        </div>'; break;

    default: $page = '
        <div class="innerbox">
            <h1>ADMIN CONTROL PANEL</h1>
        </div>'; break;

}
echo $page;
```

Is there something wrong I have done in the code? If so a quick helping hand would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: nothing looks wrong, try <p>ADMIN CONTROL PANEL</p>

Comment: @VinayWadhwa: tried and didn't make a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code should work, see [this example](http://codepad.org/vNURlJch).

Most likely the problem is that `$_GET['page']` is not set and you run into a php warning. You can avoid that by using:

```
$get = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'default or something';
switch($get) {
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but this didn't make a difference. I also forgot to say that for each case, it adds the case ID on to the end of the url for example, admin/php#todo. Does this make a difference?

Comment: @Lodder But in that case the variable would not be present in `$_GET` or are you encoding the value of `#`?

Comment: got it working now, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.